# SQL Three Table Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I am trying to write some code using 3 tables that I have to query from a database, the following is how it's laid out:

```
TableA (ID, Number, Name, etc.)

TableB (ID, Order, TableA_ID, etc.)

TableC (ID, Order, Action, Device, TableB_ID, etc.)
```

Now I need the values (*TableB.Order, TableC.Order, TableC.Action, TableC.Device*)

These values are determined from a user input which will take the value of *TableA.Number* (which has a unique ID *TableA.ID*).

```
Query = 
("SELECT TableB.Order, TableC.Order, 
         TableC.Action, TableC.Device  
    FROM TableC  
   INNER JOIN TableB  
      ON TableB.Id = TableC.TableB_Id  
   INNER JOIN TableA  
      ON TableA.Id = TableB.TableA_Id  
   WHERE TableA.Number  
    LIKE "USER INPUT") 

mycursor.execute(query)  
data = mycursor.fetchall()
```

Looking for any tips.

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'." I receive this error when running your suggestion.

Comment: Just to be sure a thing, can you check by removing `TableC.Order` from the select?

Comment: by taking out both TableB.Order & TableC.Order I was able to get an output on the python console

Comment: Don't take out both please, use one to understand the issue.

Comment: I get the same error when I just take one out

Comment: Now use the updated answer.

Comment: Yeah that solution worked. Thanks for your support, much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query should be written like below :

```
SELECT TableB.[Order] as TableB_Order, TableC.[Order] as TableC_Order, 
TableC.Action, TableC.Device
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.Id = TableB.TableA_ID
INNER JOIN TableC ON TableB.Id = TableC.TableB_ID
WHERE TableA.Number LIKE '%USER INPUT%'
```

Comment: It's great that your problem is sorted out. Don't forget to mark this answer as useful(upvote) and accept the answer [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).